# Table environment not working in report document class

Tags: tables, captions, subcaption, report

I am having an unexpected behaviour in a `report` document class. I have to use the `table` float:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
%%
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf,sf},justification = raggedright,textfont=sf,font=small} % justification = raggedright
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont={bf,sf},textfont=sf,justification=right,font=footnotesize}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{labelfont={bf,sf},textfont=sf,justification=right,font=small}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={bf,sf},textfont=sf,justification=right,font=small}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{r l}
        \hline
        ML & Machine Learning
        % and so forth
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{Commonly used shorthands}
    \label{tab:shorthands}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

What I cannot understand is: I use the same structure in an `article` document. The preambles are the same, since I shall use the same tools, obviously I change only the document class. In the `article` document the above model works fine, but in the `report` is does not. 
The error is

`Package caption Error: right undefined. \begin{table}[h!]`

Are there any discrepancies in using these floats in different document classes? In the `report` case, it does not work either in main file or in a separate chapter file.

---

**EDIT**

As suggested by @Zarko, I group on a single code snipped with only relevant packages inclusion.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You forgot to add column specification to your table environment `tabular`. For example `\begin{tabular}{cc}`. As example: `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
        a   &   b
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{...}
    \label{tab:...}
\end{table}
\end{document}
` works fine!

Comment: Please merge your codes  fragments to one SMALL but complete document which reproduce your problem (which we can test as it is). It should contain only necessary packages and your definition which are related to your problem. After last changes of your code it is not clear, what is your problem. Your table code works fine ...

Comment: As I demonstrate in the answer I just posted, the issue you're encountering is *not* related to the use of the `report` document class. Instead, it is caused by a faulty option in three of the four `\captionsetup` instructions.

Comment: Now your error is evident! You need to replace `justification=right` in your `\captionsetup`s with `justification=raggedright` (as explain you @Mico in his answer).

Comment: OK thank you for rapid feedback. However, I can not understand why a setting in a `figure` float could affect this much another float, `table`, and in a way that does not hit `table`'s caption. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: @MatteoZambra - The instruction `\captionsetup[figure]{...}` used 'raggedright' in the declaration of options, so that was fine. In contrast, `\captionsetup[table]{...}` contained a faulty option, and that's why an error message is generated when a `\caption` statement is encountered inside a `table` environment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it it just a spelling error casing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I augment your code to make it compilable, I get the following error message -- which isn't quite the same as the one you reported in your query:

```
! Package caption Error: right undefined.

See the caption package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.117 \begin{table}[h!]
```

The string `! Package caption Error: right undefined` should be a tip-off. Consider the three preamble instructions

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont={bf,sf},textfont=sf,justification=right,font=footnotesize}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{labelfont={bf,sf},textfont=sf,justification=right,font=small}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={bf,sf},textfont=sf,justification=right,font=small}
```

In all three instructions, you must replace `justification=right` with `justification=raggedright`.

Observe that the `justification=right` issue isn't present in the first of the four `\captionsetup` instructions:

```
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf,sf},justification = raggedright,textfont=sf,font=small}
```

Because the option `justification = raggedright` is correct from a purely syntactic point of you, you were so far not experiencing caption-related issues in `figure` environments, right?

Comment: Thank you, mister. Just one question: how come that an option about `figure` caption formatting could impact in this way on a different float type, `table`, and not even in something related to the caption of the latter?

Comment: @MatteoZambra - I'm not sure I understand your follow-up question. Note that `\captionsetup[figure]{...}` pertains *only* to `figure` environments, not to `table`, `subfigure`, or `algorithm` environments. The fact that you did *not* provide a faulty option in the `\captionsetup[figure]{...}` directive in no way rescues the `table`-related code from the ill effects of issuing a faulty option inside the `\captionsetup[table]{...}` directive.